# Is it possible to register a javascript event that triggers when java applet is fully loaded?

Tags: java, javascript, events, applet

I have a web application that uses java applet defined in a `<applet>` tag. Is it possible to add a javascript event that is triggered after the applet is fully loaded? This is some initialization javascript that is dependent on that the applet is fully loaded and valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have source code control over the applet, you can poll for the applet to be loaded before calling methods on it. Here is a utility function I wrote that does just that:

```
/* Attempt to load the applet up to "X" times with a delay. If it succeeds, then execute the callback function. */
function WaitForAppletLoad(applet_id, attempts, delay, onSuccessCallback, onFailCallback) {
    //Test
    var to = typeof (document.getElementById(applet_id));
    if (to == 'function' || to == 'object') {
        onSuccessCallback(); //Go do it.
        return true;
    } else {
        if (attempts == 0) {
            onFailCallback();
            return false;
        } else {
            //Put it back in the hopper.
            setTimeout(function () {
                WaitForAppletLoad(applet_id, --attempts, delay, onSuccessCallback, onFailCallback);
            }, delay);
        }
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
WaitForAppletLoad("fileapplet", 10, 2000, function () {
        BuildTree("c:/");
    }, function () {
        alert("Sorry, unable to load the local file browser.");
    });
```

Comment: I tried this, but the value of `to` is `"object"` in MSIE. Firefox give `"function"` here. I just changed the check to support both: `if (to == 'function' || to == 'object')`.

Comment: Gracias! I fixed the example to help the script kiddies.

Comment: I've just tried this and `typeof (document.getElementById(applet_id))` is always _object_ **even when the id doesn't exist!!** so it really doesn't check anything. It always fall to the successCallback for me...

Comment: Which html element are you using to embed your applet on the page? applet / object / embed?

Answer (score 5):

javascript invoking is rather simple:

Your init() method can include the jsObject declaration and javascript invoking:

```
@Override
public void init() {
// some code
  JSObject jsObject = JSObject.getWindow(this);
  jsObject.eval("your javascript");

}
```

Comment: I was hoping for some mechanisms in HTML and/or JavaScript, like setting onload="init()" on the <applet> tag or something. But if not this is possible, I might just have to apply it from within the applet as you propose...

Answer (score 2):

You have an initializer function (i think it is run) in java applet. From there you can call a javascript in the web page after initialization work.
To work you must add the MAYSCRIPT attribute to your applet definition

```
<applet id="someId" code="JavaApplet.class" codebase="/foo" archive="Applet.jar" MAYSCRIPT>
</applet>
```

Code example to invoke a JavaScript:

```
public String invokeJavaScript(Object caller, String cmd) throws TiNT4Exception {
    printDebug(2, "Start JavaScript >>" + cmd + "<<");
    try {
      // declare variables
      Method getw = null;
      Method eval = null;
      Object jswin = null;

      // create new instance of class netscape.javascript.JSObject
      Class c = Class.forName("netscape.javascript.JSObject"); // , true, this.getClass().getClassLoader()); // does it in IE too

      // evaluate methods
      Method ms[] = c.getMethods();
      for (int i = 0; i < ms.length; i ++) {
        if (ms[i].getName().compareTo("getWindow") == 0) { getw = ms[i]; }
        else if (ms[i].getName().compareTo("eval") == 0) { eval = ms[i]; }
      } // for every method

      printDebug(3, "start invokings");
      Object a[] = new Object[1];
      a[0] = caller;
      jswin = getw.invoke(c, a);
      a[0] = cmd;
      Object result = eval.invoke(jswin, a);

      if (result == null) {
        printDebug(3, "no return value from invokeJavaScript");
        return "";
      }

      if (result instanceof String) {
        return (String)result;
      } else {
        return result.toString();
      }
    } catch (InvocationTargetException ite) {
      throw new TiNT4Exception(ite.getTargetException() + "");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new TiNT4Exception(e + "");
    }
  } // invokeJavaScript
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `param` tag to pass the name of a JS function into your applet:

```
<applet id="myapplet" code="JavaApplet.class" codebase="/foo"
        archive="Applet.jar" MAYSCRIPT>
  <param name="applet_ready_callback" value="myJSfunction"/>
</applet>
```

In your applet, get the value of the param and call the function when ready:

```
@Override
public void init() {
  String jsCallbackName = getParameter("applet_ready_callback");
  JSObject jsObject = JSObject.getWindow(this);
  jsObject.eval(jsCallbackName + "()");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used another way to call a JavaScript function from an applet.

```
try {
    getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL("javascript:appletLoaded()"));
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    System.err.println("Failed to call JavaScript function appletLoaded()");
}
```

...must be called in the applet class which extends Applet or JApplet. I called the JavaScript function at the end of my start() method.

Comment: My problem is that the Applet is 3rd party, so I don't have access to change the internals of the applet. I just need to know when the applet is fully loaded, so I know when I can call methods on in.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with Java 7 SE. You can register `onLoad()` event or just poll `status`, see [Handling Initialization Status With Event Handlers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/appletStatus.html) for an example.

In order to use this functionality, you should deploy the applet with `java_status_events` parameter set to `true`.

The article [Applet Status and Event Handlers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/appletStatus.html) outlines the status and events:

> ### Status
>
> - `LOADING` = 1 - Applet is loading
> - `READY` = 2 - Applet has loaded completely and is ready to receive JavaScript calls
> - `ERROR` = 3 - Error while loading applet
>
> ### Events
>
> - **`onLoad`**: Occurs when applet status is `READY`. Applet has finished loading and is ready to receive JavaScript calls.
> - **`onStop`**: Occurs when applet has stopped.
> - **`onError`**: Occurs when applet status is `ERROR`. An error has occurred while loading the applet.
>
> You can register or determine an event handler in the JavaScript code of a web page as shown in the following code snippets.
>
> ```
> // use an anonymous function
> applet.onLoad(function() {
>   //event handler for ready state
> }
>
> // use a regular function
> function onLoadHandler() {
>   // event handler for ready state
> }
>
> // Use method form
> applet.onLoad(onLoadHandler);
>
> // Use attribute form
> applet.onLoad = onLoadHandler;
> ```