# Why doesn't 'load' event handler bound to an <applet> get called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload-event

I want a callback that is executed after an <applet> element is loaded:

```
// Create element
var $applet = $("<applet></applet>");

// Attach handler
$applet.load(function() {
    alert('applet loaded');
});

// Set attributes
$applet.attr({
    style: 'position:absolute;left:-1px',
    name: 'TiddlySaver',
    code: 'TiddlySaver.class',
    archive: 'TiddlySaver.jar',
    width:'1',
    height:'1',
});
```

**Why is the 'load' event handler not executed for an <applet> element?** If I change the <applet> to an <img> element (with valid src attribute) the handler *is* executed.

Comment: Have you tried with `<object>` instead? Using `<applet>` is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/applet

Comment: You will have to write Java code that send JavaScript code to browser when it's loaded. You can refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407300/is-it-possible-to-register-a-javascript-event-that-triggers-when-java-applet-is-f) for sample code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the HTML 4.01 (which is the fundamental standard for web pages), only two elements have an onload attribute: body and frameset. Some other elements also support it as a proprietary extension (image is fairly common), but you should not expect any other element to do so.

HTML5 requires all HTML elements (except body, which is peculiar) to support a load event, but you can't depend on it being widely or fully implemented yet (if ever).

Answer (score 1):

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/):

> This event can be sent to any element
>   associated with a URL: images,
>   scripts, frames, iframes, and the
>   window object.

That might be the reason why.