# jQuery SVG-object tag load event

Tags: jquery, onload-event, object-tag

I have a page which dynamically adds SVGs to the page via jQuery:

```
grid.append($('<object>')
.load(function () {
    // do stuff
    alert('loaded')
})
.attr({
    id: 'tile',
    type: 'image/svg+xml',
    width: Math.round(tile_w),
    height: Math.round(tile_h),
    data: 'map/base.svg'
})
);
```

I need access to the SVG document (to "push" a variable into the svg script context) but the SVG has to be loaded for that. My problem is that I dont get the load event working. No alert is displayed.

How to do?

**Edit:** It seems like jQuery simply prevents to bind a "load" event to a non-image-or-document element, so I just use the "official" addEventListener() function (not supported by stupid IE, but this is no problem for me):

```
grid.append($('<embed>')
    .attr({
        id: 'tile' + i,
        type: 'image/svg+xml',
        width: Math.round(tile_w),
        height: Math.round(tile_h),
        src: 'map/base.svg'
     })
    .css({
        position: 'absolute',
        left: Math.round(p.x),
        top: Math.round(p.y)
    }).each(function (i){
        this.addEventListener ('load', function (e) {
            alert('loaded')
        })
    })
);
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what `grid` is in your example but if it is a normal dom element then the `load` api call should be of the format defined in the api docs. Currently it looks like you are trying to load a function call which doesn't make any sense.

```
.load( url [, data] [, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)] )
```

so

```
grid.append($('<object>').load('image.svg',
    function (response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == 'success') {
            // yay the load is ok
            alert('loaded');
        }
    })
);
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

UPDATE: I haven't tried lodaing SVG data into the browser with HTML but the W3C docs don't mention that the `<object>` tag could be used for that. Their example uses `<embed>`

```
<embed src="circle1.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
```

have you tried using that instead of `<object>`?

**UPDATE 2:**

I don't think the above solution will work either, since the JS `onload` event is supported by the following tags `<body>, <frame>, <frameset>, iframe, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script>, <style>` - I assume this is what jQuery is hooking into, thus it'll only work for those elements. The jQuery docs say that the event handler is supported by `images, scripts, frames, iframes` and the `window` object.

So indeed if that doesn't work, then I suppose you'll just need to use the `.load()` method call and handle the results. Maybe you can put the svg embed tags into separate html files, or have a script that generates the html embeds.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

**UPDATE 3:**

There would appear to be at least two correct solutions to this problem.

1. jQuery SVG plugin http://keith-wood.name/svg.html
2. a jQuery `ajax()` call detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802283/jquery-appending-to-ajax-loaded-svg-problem) including information about interacting
   with the svg canvas after load.

Comment: As it seems to me he is trying to use `load` not as an `ajax` function but simply as a DOM`load` event handler. There is a pretty much questions on SO related to DOM load and object element

Comment: Hm, i want to the load-event but the ajax call  http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: The question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926424 is about the same problem but does not provide a solution.

Comment: No, when using embed the load event does not fire, too.

Comment: @Euro see update 2 above - basically the embed tag doesn't support the javascript `onload` event so there is nothing for jQuery to hook into.

Comment: @Euro, may be it is better to do it via ajax? Load the `svg` and append it to the page? This will work without such bugs

Comment: Yeah, reading through the comments section on the `load` event handler it seems to be rife with problems and cross browser incompatibilities.

Comment: The problem with the ajax call is that it destroys the relative paths in the svg code (like for external css files). If i use addEventListener instead of jQuery the event is fired...