# how to check whether java applet is completely loaded using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, applet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to register a javascript event that triggers when java applet is fully loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407300/is-it-possible-to-register-a-javascript-event-that-triggers-when-java-applet-is)

I have java appplets on my page.

I need to detect whether java applet is loaded completely or not using `javascript/ jquery`.

I tried with `applet.isActive()` but it not giving the proper results.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407300/is-it-possible-to-register-a-javascript-event-that-triggers-when-java-applet-is?rq=1

Comment: @goldenparrot , My context is different from that, I have a loading popup for applet. On loading popup there is a stop link, if applet taking more time user can click on stop link. then I need to remove the applet container.